# Software wiki framework that jupyter's doc uses?

Tags: python, document-management, documentation-generator, documentation-viewer, jekyll

I'm looking at the jupyter platform docs

https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

looks like this

[image]

I've seen this platform many times

What is it called?

It looks similar to jekyll documentation, but wappylzer is telling me its python

What's this framework called on the jupyter's read docs page?

is the jupyter docs actually based on jupyter?

Comment: https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/818/is-software-identification-on-topic

Comment: okay i modified the question to be more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of the page you will find the words:

> Built with Sphinx using a theme provided by Read the Docs.

[Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/) is a python based document generation tool and *personally I find it absolutely brilliant*.